# how to send an interactive email

Tags: php, html, css, email, interactive

I'm trying to send an **interactive email** to my customers. In the bellow code `content.html` page contains the content of the email body which contains only the html and css. `sendmail.php` will send the email to the receivers email address.

Email is sending successfully by the `sendmail.php` but in the email the html body is not working as expected.

Body of the email should work as in this example:
https://codepen.io/freshinbox/pen/worqww

But the email display it as this:
[image: sample image]

I tried with both gmail and hotmail accounts, but the result is same.

***content.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.keybox{
 display:inline-block;
border:10px solid black;
}
.keybox label{
width:65px;
height:55px;
display:none;
padding-top:5px;
font-size:40px;
text-align:center;
}  
#key1a:checked ~ .kinetic .box1 label:nth-child(2){
display:block;
}
#key1b:checked ~ .kinetic .box1 label:nth-child(3){
display:block;
}
#key1c:checked ~ .kinetic .box1 label:nth-child(4){
display:block;
}
#key1d:checked ~ .kinetic .box1 label:nth-child(1){
display:block;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>

<input id="key1a" name="key1" type=radio>
<input id="key1b" name="key1" type=radio>
<input id="key1c" name="key1" type=radio>
<input id="key1d" name="key1" type=radio checked><BR>
<div class="kinetic">  
<div class="keybox box1">
    <label for="key1a">X</label>
    <label for="key1b">G</label>
    <label for="key1c">H</label>
    <label for="key1d">A</label>
</div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

***sendmail.php***

```
<?php
if(($Content = file_get_contents("content.html")) === false) {
    $Content = "";
}

$FromName = "Sample";
$FromEmail = "myemail@email.com";
$ReplyTo = "youremail@email.com";
$ToEmail = "youremail@email.com";
$Subject = "Test";

$Headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$Headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$Headers .= "From: ".$FromName." <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "Reply-To: ".$ReplyTo."\n";
$Headers .= "X-Sender: <".$FromEmail.">\n";
$Headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n"; 
$Headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; 
$Headers .= "Return-Path: <".$FromEmail.">\n";  

if(mail($ToEmail, $Subject, $Content, $Headers) == false) {
    echo "ERRRO!";
}
else{
    echo "OK!";
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot have embedded or included style-sheet in Emails. You need to have it inline. Given your stuff, there's no way you can send any interactive content this way.

Comment: Use `inline-css` to add styling in your html. You can't use css like this when sending mails.

Comment: @PraveenKumar look at  [this](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/code-tutorial-how-to-build-an-interactive-puzzle-in-email?utm_referrer=freshinbox.com) example. They are saying that we can send interactive emails.

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage Dude, which email client are you targeting? Definitely you can't get this thing working in GMail.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Im mainly targeting gmail, outlook, and yahoo.
can please tell me how to make this work?

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage Negative bro... Possible illa... `:(` Sorry.

Comment: @AnkitSingh So is there an example how to change authors content.html to contain styles "inline" instead of in style tag? I could not find exact information on this.

I am trying to get the same thing as author. I want to send a letter with long text and I want the reader to be able to switch between parts of this text by clicking on "tabs" or radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browser do not support some of the CSS rules you have used, for example:

Gmail and Outlook both do not support `~` or `:nth-child`.

There is a good CSS support guide here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Although this graph does not say - I am fairly sure Gmail and Outlook also do not support `:checked`.

[image]

[image]

Some browsers will let you use these rules, but unless you're deliberately targeting a specific set of users with a certain email client, there is no sure way of getting it right for everyone.

Comment: Ha! I was searching for this link... And you posted.

Comment: @Albzi can you please tell me to make this wok or is there any tutorials that i can follow sending interactive emails for any email client

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage Unfortunately if you look at the graph in the link, you will see that not every browser supports all the rules in CSS. Emails have always been a battle and unfortunately you won't be able to create an interactive email that works on every client.